# Django 2. Как обновить поле(id) в моделе?

Tags: django, django-orm

Есть модель

```
class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

После удаление объектов из БД, нумерация продолажется с последней цифры. Нужно чтобы после удаления поля нумерация начиналась с 0.

Comment: Не нужно. Вся суть идентификаторов в их неизменности.

Comment: Во-первых, действительно не нужно, во-вторых, это делается в СУБД и Django здесь ни при чём

Answer (score 0):

Можно полностью очистить базу

```
python manage.py flush
```

Comment: а можно конкретную таблицу?

Comment: Если интересует удаление данных одной конкретной модели, то в `python manage.py shell` 
`from App import Model` 
>>> `Model.objects.all().delete()`

Comment: блин, ТОЧНО!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
python manage.py dbshell
pqsql> ALTER TABLE <table_name> AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```